# Не работает функция, срабатывающая при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется код, где я присваиваю переменной кнопку. При нажатии кнопки в идеале должна появиться запись в консоли. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

```js
let сhooseButtonAdd = document.querySelector('.btnAdd');
    
    function addAuto() {
       console.log('asdasdasdasd');
    }
    
    chooseButtonAdd.addEventListener('onclick', addAuto);
    console.log(chooseButtonAdd);
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  <button class="btnAdd" type="button">
    Добавить автомобиль
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

У Вас в названии кнопки `сhooseButtonAdd` первая буква `c` русская.
Вам необходимо вызывать `click` вместо `onclick`.

```js
    let сhooseButtonAdd = document.querySelector('.btnAdd');

    function addAuto() {
        console.log('asdasdasdasd');
    }

    сhooseButtonAdd.addEventListener('click', addAuto);
```

```html
<div class="btn">
    <button class="btnAdd" type="button">
        Добавить автомобиль
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: да. скопипастил в редактор. Однако в консоли браузера по-прежнему ругается на "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at admin.js:7"

Comment: @ПавелПетров Ваш скрипт выполняется до создания DOM-элемента. Поместите его внизу страницы или заверните в `window.addEventListener('load', function(){...});`.

Comment: @ПавелПетров Я не знаю, для чего у Вас добавлен обработчик события. Перечитайте мой комментарий. Не торопитесь. Подумайте.

Comment: Ну изначально, по задуманной логике поведения страницы, скрипт должен срабатывать по нажатию кнопки. Код из ответа от Denis640Kb на этом сайте работает, однако при запуске в моем проекте, он почему то не срабатывает и ошибка не изменяется. Мне просто неохота функцию встраивать в html-код, поэтому и хочется через данный принцип реализовать поведение кнопки

Comment: @ПавелПетров Не торопитесь. Строчки `let сhooseButtonAdd = document.querySelector('.btnAdd');
` и `сhooseButtonAdd.addEventListener('click', addAuto);` выполняются сразу, а не по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: @Igor function addAuto() {
    let chooseButtonAdd = document.getElementById('btnAdd');
    chooseButtonAdd.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log('asdasdasdasd');
    })

}

window.addEventListener('load', addAuto); данный код сработал. Ну, это понятно, что скрипт выполнялся сразу же после загрузки страницы. Но почему именно в таком варианте код сработал?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106117/discussion-between---and-igor).